# issue with inserting values into database in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hey guys so I am trying to insert some strings into my wordpress database, it proceeds but nothing is sent over, no values are stored for some reason.

Here is the code:

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->discount_info_guest
        ( firstname, lastname, email )
        VALUES ( %s, %s, %s )
    ", 
     $firstname, 
    $lastname, 
    $email 
) );
echo"working";
exit;
```

Let me know what you think, and if you need any other info.

Thanks!

Database:

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   
ID  bigint(60)      UNSIGNED    No      auto_increment  
firstname   varchar(60) utf8_general_ci     No  
email   varchar(60) utf8_general_ci     No
discount_code_used  varchar(60) utf8_general_ci     No  
order_state varchar(10) utf8_general_ci     No  1

    Indexes:  
Keyname Type    Cardinality 
    PRIMARY  PRIMARY     0
```

Comment: Is the property `$wpdb->discount_info_guest` set? And does the table for that value exist?

Comment: look above at what it looks like

Comment: Please show the value of that class property `$wpdb->discount_info_guest`

Comment: You are using `INSERT INTO $wpdb->discount_info_guest`. `$wpdb->discount_info_guest` is a variable. What is it's value and is it the same name as your table?

Comment: have you written global $wpdb; before running query.

Comment: run your query without using prepare funtion.

Comment: @anuj I thought you just solved it, I forgot to totally do that, but it still does not add to database.

Comment: @ben $wpdb->discount_info_guest is just how it calls it...its the table so the $wpdb adds the wp_ in front.  No idea why but that's just how they declare them.

Comment: use this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb . find for insert and you can find a way.

Comment: Okay @benjaminpaap you were right actually I took away the $wpdb-> from the discount and just manually added the wp_ in front.  Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: and also i hope that wp doesn't automatically detect $wpdb->discount_info_guest, as this is your custom table, so if you try writing directly the table name. Wish it may work.

Comment: table name is probably wrong

Answer (score 0):

$wpdb->discount_info_guest should be {$wpdb->prefix}discount_info_guest